# How to stop Firefox for Android from constantly displaying its Mozilla tab

Tags: firefox-for-android

Every time I let my phone display turn off, and then unlock it and return to Firefox, or just go to another app or hit my home button and then go back to Firefox, it's showing its Mozilla tab. That's the one that lists the following items: About Firefox, FAQs, Give feedback, Show product announcements, Telemetry, Crash Reporter, and Firefox Health Report.  I can hit the back button on my phone and get back to whatever page it was viewing, but then as soon as I leave and come back, that list is up again. I'm using Android version 2.3.6 and Firefox version 32.0.3 on a MyTouchQ phone.

Comment: What Firefox version is this? What phone and Android version do you have? I've never seen the behaviour you describe, so I'd like to know more.

Comment: @DanHulme I updated the question. I also have a 2013 Nexus 7 with Firefox on it and yeah, I've never had this problem on that device.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question here on the Mozilla Support site is a similar problem to yours:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1013146

Otherwise...try uninstalling/re-installing the app. Also...you could always download a different browser.

Comment: Thanks, but that is a different issue. When I open a new tab, I get the normal top sites/history/etc page.  It's just when I click the home button on my phone or go to another app, I get that Mozilla tab overlay.  I forgot to mention in my initial question that I did try uninstalling and reinstalling.